# Can I rely on the ordering of the adjacency matrix?

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have created a Graph[{1,2..n}, {1->3, etc}], and I take the adjacency matrix of that graph. Can I rely on the fact that the i-th entry in the graph is the i-th node in the matrix? Or maybe the neighbors of the nodes are at a different row?

Comment: From the docs `The vertices Subscript[v, i] are assumed to be in the order given by VertexList[g].`

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  But don't assume that the vertex named `1` is the first one, etc. That is often not the case.  You can get the order of vertices using `VertexList`.  You can get the index of a certain vertex using `VertexIndex`.

From the documentation of [`AdjacencyMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html),

> The vertices $v_i$ are assumed to be in the order given by `VertexList[g]`.

Comment: I have the impression ( but can't check that right now) that if you provide a list of nodes as the first argument the order used will be the order of the node list.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries That's correct AFAIK, I was too lazy to point that out.  However, if the vertex list is not explicitly given then in the current version it just takes the order of vertices as they first appear in the edge list.  In future versions, who knows?